# Write Excel formula to Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi guys i have 2  excel Workbook

im trying to write down the formula through vba macro

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim WorkbookName As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet


WorkbookName = "WhatsApp_IF_SuspenseAging_082023.xlsx"

' set the workbook object
On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks(WorkbookName) ' first try to see if the workbook already open
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then ' if workbook = Nothing (workbook is closed)
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\RPA\IDN-OPS-POS-08_SuspenseAging\Status_WA\082023\" & WorkbookName)
End If

' set the worksheet object

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A3,[WhatsApp_IF_SuspenseAging_082023.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A,0))), IF(INDIRECT(CELL(" & """address""" & ",INDEX([WhatsApp_IF_SuspenseAging_082023.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$O,MATCH(A3,[WhatsApp_IF_SuspenseAging_082023.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A,0),15)))=" & """No""" & ", TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)"

End Sub
```

But there is always error 1004

When i copy manually the code into the cell it works fine

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,[WhatsApp_IF_SuspenseAging_082023.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A,0))), IF(@INDIRECT(@CELL("address",INDEX([WhatsApp_IF_SuspenseAging_082023.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$O,MATCH(A2,[WhatsApp_IF_SuspenseAging_082023.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A,0),15)))="No", TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)
```

Comment: Instead `Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Value` try `Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Formula` and LastRow is not declared is it Global?

Comment: @Blackcat sorry i missed copied script, its .Formula but the error keeps coming

Comment: LastRow is 0 if you not set a value for it

Comment: @Blackcat oh my god im sorry thanks for the solution